# Prevent Boostrap modal closing after LinkButton Click inside modal

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I got a LinkButton inside a boostrap modal with a ClickFunction in codeBehind. Everytime that i click in linkButton and event in codebehind is firing, the modal is closing. I wanna to keep modal open after a linkbutton click!

Check the asp LinkButton inside modal on tag **modal-body** with a Click event:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalPesquisaCliente" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Fechar</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="txtTitle"><i>&nbsp;Pesquisa de Clientes</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="link" OnClick="link_Click">aaa</asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

LinkButton Click function in code Behind:

```
 protected void link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl.Text = "aaa";
    }
```

The issue is: Everytime i click link button inside modal, which have a
 click event in codebehind, the modal is closing?

I just wanted to keep modal opened once the linkbutton was clicked

Comment: try to keep `data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"`  to your div modal and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FOUND SOLUTION GUYS! THE ANSWER IS:

" When you use UPDATE PANEL and occours a postback, the postback act in all controls inside update panel, and if modals html code is inside update panel, when postback occours, the modal will be "refreshed" and seted to default value again (Thats in closed state), so if you wanna to keep modal open after a postback, you should  write this html code OUT of update panel, doing this every time a postback occour inside update panel, the code of modal doesn't be "touched" and "re wrote" by postback.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned jQuery, try this

```
 $(document).on('click', '#link', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set modal property like below to prevent disappear modal popup :

```
$('#modalPesquisaCliente').modal({
  backdrop: 'static',
  keyboard: false
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap model either jQuery with URL action to your code behind method or Update panel using with Scriptmanager.

WebForm:

```
<asp:Button ID="link" runat="server" OnClientClick="callAjaxMethod(event)"  Text="Call method using Ajax" />
```

Code behind:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static bool link_Click()
{
return "aaa";
}
```

jQuery:

```
function callAjaxMethod(e) {

e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "SimpleAjax.aspx/IsLeapYear",
data: '',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function (response) {
  if (response.d) {
     $('#<%=lbl.ClientID%>').val(response.d);
  }
  else {
    $('#<%=lbl.ClientID%>').val('No value');
  }
},
failure: function (response) {
  $('#<%=lbl.ClientID%>').val("Error in calling Ajax:" + response.d);
}
});
}
```

Second Method using Update Panel

WebForm:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <fieldset>
            <div class="modal fade" id="modalPesquisaCliente" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Fechar</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="txtTitle"><i>&nbsp;Pesquisa de Clientes</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="link" OnClick="link_Click">aaa</asp:LinkButton>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </fieldset>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind: as it is no change

```
 protected void link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    lbl.Text = "aaa";
 }
```

And one very simple method to use without using jquery or update panel, you can use simple jQuery to .

jQuery:

```
 $(document).on('click', '#<%=link.ClientID%>', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

event.preventDefault(); for

To prevent postback from happening as we are ASP.Net TextBox control so If we had used input **html element**, there *is no need to use* ' e.preventDefault()' as posback will not happen.